# ANSI C code for both Objective-C and C++ code?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, split, c-preprocessor

In my project there are 3 possible types of files: pure C/Objective-C, pure C++ or Objective-C++ code.

How to divide functions in .h file with `#define` directives into parts to make this file available for all these files? I don't want to rename all the .m files to .mm because of problems with refactoring.

I know that I can write .h file in C which uses C++ .cpp file using the following code:

```
#ifndef Chadstone_CCCWrapper_h
#define Chadstone_CCCWrapper_h

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string.h>
extern "C"
{
#endif

    void minMaxCoordinates(char *c, float *minX, float *minY, float *maxX, float *maxY);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif
```

but what if I want to add functions with using of `NSString` or `list<...>`.

Comment: How would you compile the implementation file?

Comment: it is currently .cpp, it simply contains `#include`s and `minMaxCoordinates` implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it in standard pch-file genarated by Xcode:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#endif
```

Also you need use `CF_EXPORT` macro when declaring function to prevent linkage errors.

Example:

```
#ifndef SOME_H_FILE
#define SOME_H_FILE

#ifdef __OBJC__

@interface SomeObjClass: NSObject
@end

CF_EXPORT void SomeFunctionWithNSString(NSString* str);

#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus

class SomeCPlusPlustClass
{
};

CF_EXPORT void someFunctionWithList(const list<int>& intList);

#ifdef __OBJ__
CF_EXPORT void someComplicatedFunction(NSString* str, const list<int>& intList);
#endif

#endif

CF_EXPORT void someFunction();

typedef struct _SomeStruct
{
} SomeStruct;

#endif
```

Comment: Not a complete answer.  Also please provide details of how the implementation file is compiled.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Thank you. I have added example. Please tell me if I missed something.

Comment: Looks pretty good.  I'm still unclear of the OP intentions, but never mind.  They are probably misguided.

Comment: can you describe each part more briefly? And if I know that all the functions defined in 3 various ways have different names then should I use this macro too?

Comment: @user2083364, `CF_EXPORT` add `extern "C"` if `__cplusplus` defined. You don't need it if you write `#ifdef __cplusplust extern "C" { #endif`